# How can I get the red checker pieces and blue checker piece to highlight when I click on using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var cells = $(".cell");
    var colorCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = $(cells[i]);
        var isDark = colorCount % 2 == 0;
        var isNextRow = (i + 1) % 8 == 0;
        colorCount += isNextRow ? 2 : 1;
        cell.css("background-color", isDark ? "navy" : "white"); 
    }
    $(".cell piece red").on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); }
    });
    $(".cell piece blue").on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");  }
    });
});
```

```css
.home > .board
{
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.home > .board > .row
{
    display: table;
}

.home > .board > .row > .cell
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.piece
{
    background-size: 75px 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

.red
{
    background-image: URL('../images/red.png');
}

.black
{
    background-image: URL('../images/black.png');
}
```

```html
@model CheckerBoard.Models.HomeModel

<html>

    <head>
        <title>@Model.PageTitle</title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>

            <div class="home">
            
                <div class="board">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

How can I get the red checker pieces and blue checker pieces to highlight when I click on them? Also, is there a JQuery method for moving the pieces to the different spots on the checkerboard without using JQuery UI methods for moving or highlighting? I am new at JQuery and I want to learn more about. JQuery is easy to understand at it's minimal basic methods but not for what I am trying to do. Can anyone help? I have tried using the methods that you see in the js file but when I refresh my page nothing happens. Why is that? Is it a flaw in Visual Studio Express 2013 or wrong syntax? Please help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Put dots for every class, if they are together make them together like this `$(".cell.piece.red")`

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var cells = $(".cell");
    var colorCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = $(cells[i]);
        var isDark = colorCount % 2 == 0;
        var isNextRow = (i + 1) % 8 == 0;
        colorCount += isNextRow ? 2 : 1;
        cell.css("background-color", isDark ? "navy" : "white"); 
    }
    $(".cell.piece.red").on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); }
    });
    $(".cell.piece.blue").on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");  }
    });
});
```

```css
.home > .board
{
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.home > .board > .row
{
    display: table;
}

.home > .board > .row > .cell
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.piece
{
    background-size: 75px 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

.red
{
    background-image: URL('../images/red.png');
}

.black
{
    background-image: URL('../images/black.png');
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>@Model.PageTitle</title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>

            <div class="home">
            
                <div class="board">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Nic explained bellow, there's nothing more i can say, best regards.

Comment: how do I move the pieces to a different spot?

Comment: @ happymacarts is there another way to do it without using JQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax requires an identifier for each class/id.

```
$( ".cell.piece.red" ).click(function() {
    // do
});
```

A space between identifiers signifies the child of. No space between identifiers signifies multiple identifiers for the same element.

For example,

`.cell.piece.red` would find `<div class="cell piece red"></div>`

`.cell .piece .red` would find

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="piece">
        <div class="red"></div> // this line
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I drag or move the pieces to different spots on the checkerboard?